# Kendu Upload is not passing dropdown value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

When I use Kendu Upload control I can't get my dropdown value to the controller.  When I don't use Kendu upload and just a regular input and button, the value is passed to the controller.  I'm thinking it has to be something with ASYNC postback.  Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can anybody see the pictures I uploaded to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way:

```
 upload: function(e)
          {
              var additional = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
                    e.data = JSON.parse(additional);
          }
```

and in controller
public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase files, ViewModel additional)
{
}